# How to zoom web view page in android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

Hello every one I am using `WebView` in android and I want to zoom the page that is loaded on my web view. I am using the following settings:

```
    wb.getSetting().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb.getSetting().setSupportZoom(true);
    wb.loadUrl("https://www.mywebsite.com/");
```

Before the webpage loads the zoom control show correctly, but after the webpage loads the zoom control is gone.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

```
wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wb.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```